# Condition for roots to he collinear in a plane

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find necessary and sufficient conditions for a,b,c,d so that the equations:
z²+az+b=0 , z²+cz+d=0 ;                 are collinear in the plane.

I found this question in a book named "Challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics", unfortunately i am unable to solve it ; any hints and solutions would be appreciable

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez sorry i was unable to explain the question but i pasted it as it was in the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what you mean by equations that are colinear in the plane. I assumed you meant the complex roots of these equations are colinear in the $\mathbb{C}$ plane.

Roots of the two polynomial are $\frac {-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}} 2$ and $\frac {-c \pm \sqrt{c^2-4d}} 2$.

If the four roots are colinear, they are also colinear with the middle of the roots of each polynomial, which are $-\frac a 2$ and $-\frac c 2$.
This is also equivalent to saying that the difference $\sqrt{a^2-4b}$ or $\sqrt{c^2-4d}$ between two roots of the same polynomial is colinear with the difference $\frac {c-a} 2$ between the middles of the root pairs.

So we are left with two conditions:
$\begin{cases}
\frac {\sqrt{a^2-4b}} {c-a} \in \mathbb{R} \\
\frac {\sqrt{c^2-4d}} {c-a} \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$

Which is equivalent to:
$\begin{cases}
\frac {a^2-4b} {(c-a)^2} \in \mathbb{R}^+ \\
\frac {c^2-4d} {(c-a)^2} \in \mathbb{R}^+
\end{cases}$

Note that, if $a,b,c,d$ are all real numbers, the conditions found say that both polynomials have a positive discriminant, hence have real roots, which are therefore colinear.